# Making a gdb log file

Tags: logging, gdb, cpu

I need to make a gdb log on my process , if it uses 100% of CPU.

Here is my script I got at the moment written in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

ID=`top -n 1 | grep server | awk '{print $1}'`
CPU_PERCENT=`top -n 1 | grep server | awk '{print $9}'`
GDB_m = `gdb server $ID --cd /home/rox/rl`

echo "Checking CPU..."

if [ $CPU_PERCENT -eq 100 ]
then
echo "CPU 100%, running the script, for the process with ID: $ID"
while true
do
    gdb server $ID --cd /home/private_user/servers
    echo "bt full" >> $GDB_m
    echo "exit" >> $GDB_m
    echo "y" >> $GDB_m
    echo "Sleeping for 60 seconds..."
    sleep 60
done
else
echo "CPU $CPU_PERCENT %, its fine!"
sleep 1
fi
```

It was written by me, and it doesn't save a log or anything, there is an error with the `$ID` , or something because when I'm running it, its saying:

> /home/private_user/servers/server/21337: There is no such file or
>   directory.

Answer (score 0):

top aligns fields, so you might end up with results where the first record in awk ($1) is an empty string. I'd change

```
ID=`top -n 1 | grep server | awk '{print $1}'`
CPU_PERCENT=`top -n 1 | grep server | awk '{print $9}'`
```

to

```
ID=`top -n 1 | grep server | awk '{print (NF>13 ? $2 : $1)}'`
CPU_PERCENT=`top -n 1 | grep server | awk '{print (NF>13 ? $10 : $9)}'`
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: Not helped // sorry for the delay.

Comment: Does `gdb server $ID --cd /home/private_user/servers` work when you run it manually? I would have thought it'd be `gdb server $ID -cd /proc/` (single hyphen instead of a double).